# Chart JS - Displaying incorrect labels / data

Tags: flask, chart.js

I'm trying to create several line graphs, with daily, monthly and active users in Chart JS and Flask. As an example, I want the first graph to display the number of users per day for the previous 30 days. Here is the code below:

Route

```
# set default time period
    time_period = 'daily'

    # calculate start and end time based on time period
    end_time = datetime.now()
    if time_period == 'daily':
        start_time = end_time - timedelta(days=29)
        print(start_time)
        step = timedelta(days=1)
        date_format = '%d %b %Y'
        label_format = '%d %b %Y'
    elif time_period == 'weekly':
        start_time = end_time - timedelta(weeks=51)
        print(start_time)
        step = timedelta(weeks=1)
        date_format = '%d %b %Y'
        label_format = '%d %b %Y'
    elif time_period == 'monthly':
        start_time = end_time - timedelta(days=364)
        print(start_time)
        step = timedelta(days=30)
        date_format = '%b %Y'
        label_format = '%b %Y'

    # query user sessions
    sessions = UserSession.query.filter(
        UserSession.start_time >= start_time,
        UserSession.end_time <= end_time
    ).all()
    
    # calculate number of users
    user_counts = {}
    for session in sessions:
        session_date = session.start_time.date()
        if session_date not in user_counts:
            user_counts[session_date] = set()
        user_counts[session_date].add(session.user_id)

    # create a list of dates and user counts
    date_list = []
    user_count_list = []
    for date in user_counts.keys():
        date_list.append(date)
        user_count_list.append(len(user_counts[date]))

    # create a list of labels
    label_list = []
    current_date = start_time
    while current_date <= end_time:
        if time_period == 'monthly':
            label_list.append(current_date.strftime(label_format))
        else:
            label_list.append(current_date.strftime(date_format))
        current_date += step


    data_dict = {
    'daily': {'label': 'Daily Users', 'data': user_count_list[-30:], 'labels': label_list[-29:], 'date_format': date_format},
    'weekly': {'label': 'Weekly Users', 'data': [sum(user_count_list[i:i+7])/7 for i in range(len(user_count_list)-52, len(user_count_list), 7)], 'labels': label_list[-52:], 'date_format': date_format},
    'monthly': {'label': 'Monthly Users', 'data': [sum(user_count_list[i:i+30])/30 for i in range(len(user_count_list)-365, len(user_count_list), 30)], 'labels': label_list[-12:], 'date_format': date_format}
}
```

Jinja

```
<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="myChart"style="height: 300px;"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script>
    // Get data from Flask
    var data = {{ data_dict['daily']|tojson }};
    
    // Create new Chart instance
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: data['labels'],
        datasets: [{
          label: data['label'],
          data: data['data'],
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 0.3)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 204, 1)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
          x: {
            ticks: {
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                return moment(value, data['date_format']).format('DD MMM YYYY');
              }
            }
          },
          y: {
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              precision: 0,
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Daily User Sessions'
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
```

The problem I'm facing is it's showing the previous 4 days (with the wrong ticks) and then future invalid dates. I'll post screenshots below to demonstrate.

[image]

[image]